# Rails - Creating Associated Object with URL params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, url-parameters

I’m wanting to create an Asset from an Organisation Show page. I need the Organisation ID to be passed to the Asset for creation.

```
# ../models/organisation.rb
has_many :assets

# ../models/asset.rb
belongs_to :organisation
```

I have a button to create an asset, which is passing the organisation.id in the URL params.

```
# ../views/organisations/show.html.erb    
<%= link_to 'New Asset', new_asset_path(:organisation_id => @organisation.id) %>
```

I'm able to access the `organisation_id` value in the `../views/assets/new` view, however, when I submit the form I'm receiving a `“Method not allowed”` error.

```
# ../controllers/assets_controller.rb

def create
    @asset = Asset.new(params[:organisation_id])
    ...
end
```

Q1: Why am I getting this error:

Q2: Is there another way to pass the organisation_id through to the Asset new page? I.e. not in the URL.

Q3: If I can only pass the ID through the URL, Is there a way to stop a user tampering with it? I.e. changing the Org ID to something else and saving the asset to another organisation.

Q4: Would nested resources help in this instance?

Rails 5.0.0.1, Ruby 2.3.1

Comment: You need to tell `Asset.new` what the organisation_id param is *for* eg: `@asset = Asset.new(:organisation_id => params[:organisation_id])` otherwise you're just passing it a random number and it's going "wtf is this?" :D (well, technically it's looking for a version of the `new` method that takes a single argument that isn't a hash... which it can't find, then telling you that method doesn't exist... but same diff). ;)

Comment: Makes sense - thanks.

Comment: made into an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell `Asset.new` what the `organisation_id` param is for eg:

```
@asset = Asset.new(:organisation_id => params[:organisation_id])
```

otherwise you're just passing it a random number and it's going "wtf is this?" :D

(well, technically it's looking for a version of the new method that takes a single argument that isn't a hash... which it can't find, then telling you that method doesn't exist... but same diff). ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use like:

```
  def create
    @asset = Asset.new(organisation_id:params[:organisation_id])
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Q.1 - The error is due to the name of the model - "Assets". This is a reserved word in Rails.

It can be fixed by moving the asset pipeline to another mount point. For example:

```
# config/initializers/assets.rb

Rails.application.config.assets.prefix = '/pipeline_assets'
```

As mentioned here:

[405 Error when trying to POST a file in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122831/405-error-when-trying-to-post-a-file-in-rails)

[Rails 4 Method Not Allowed after Upgrading from Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484716/rails-4-method-not-allowed-after-upgrading-from-rails-3/32217207)